# Python script being cached after upgrade to 3.6.2

Tags: python, bytecode

Got python install under /usr/local --prefix. I upgraded from 3.5 to 3.6.2 and now Python is caching my script some where. Anytime I make a change to the script, the change is ignore and python executes the old script.

I am not talking a module, am well aware of the .pyc bytecode python creates for modules. I am talking about the main script. I see no __ files or directories under the same directory where the script resides.

How can I turn off this script level bytecode caching?

Comment: Edit your question to include an example of how you run the script.

Comment: Are you editing the file you're executing?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling python 3.6.2 with no custom settings which fixed the issue.